# Need help on PHP GET code

Tags: php, get

Right now I am using this code to grab a variable in my URL:

```
<?php

$transaction_id = $_GET['transaction_id'];

if($transaction_id == "") {
$transaction_id = 'NA';
}

?>
```

So far I have only been grabbing that single variable, but now I need to grab a total of 5 variables. Will everything still work properly and operate fast and smoothly if I just copy and paste multiple codes right next to each other like this:

```
<?php

$transaction_id = $_GET['transaction_id'];

if($transaction_id == "") {
$transaction_id = 'NA';
}

?>
<?php

$transaction_id2 = $_GET['transaction_id2'];

if($transaction_id2 == "") {
$transaction_id2 = 'NA';
}

?>
<?php

$transaction_id3 = $_GET['transaction_id3'];

if($transaction_id3 == "") {
$transaction_id3 = 'NA';
}

?>
```

Or is there a more efficient way to combine them all into one code?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Combine them all into one `<?php ... ?>` block.

Comment: You can use something like `$transaction_id3 = ($_GET['transaction_id3']!="") ? $_GET['transaction_id3']:'NA';` instead of assign the variable and then check

Comment: yes that will work fine, but you don't need to close and then reopen the `<?php` tags after each one

Answer (score 1):

Make use of **`isset()`** construct

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['transaction_id'])) {
$transaction_id = 'NA';
}
if(!isset($_GET['transaction_id2'])) {
$transaction_id2 = 'NA';
}
if(!isset($_GET['transaction_id3'])) {
$transaction_id3 = 'NA';
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe `$transaction_id3 = (isset($_GET['transaction_id3']) && !empty($_GET['transaction_id3'])) ? $_GET['transaction_id3']:'NA';` ?

Answer (score 0):

justo to be sure them all are setted and not empty

```
$na = 'NA';    

$transaction_id = (isset($_GET['transaction_id']) && $_GET['transaction_id'] != '') ? $_GET['transaction_id'] : $na ;
$transaction_id2 = (isset($_GET['transaction_id2']) && $_GET['transaction_id2'] != '') ? $_GET['transaction_id2'] : $na ;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do a for loop

```
<?php 
    $transaction_id = array();
    for($i=1;$i<6:$i++){
        if( $_GET['transaction_id'.$i] == "") {
            $transaction_id[] = 'NA'
        }else{
            $transaction_id[] = $_GET['transaction_id'.$i]
        }
    }
?>
```

This will make an array of transaction ids or NA

```
[0] => NA
[1] => 12345
[2] => 67890
[3] => 23454
[4] => NA
[5] => 55422
```

I don't know if this is better practice or not, maybe its just a different way. 
Hope it helps.

P.S. 
you will have to change your first `$_GET['transaction_id'];` to `$_GET['transaction_id1'];`